# databricks feature store Exception: "Invalid complex data type details 'None'"

Tags: databricks

I am trying out the databricks feature store. Just following [this notebook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/_extras/notebooks/source/machine-learning/feature-store-basic-example.html)

I get the error `Exception: {'error_code': 'INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE', 'message': "Invalid complex data type details 'None'"}` when doing

```
fs.create_table(
    name=table_name,
    primary_keys=["wine_id"],
    df=features_df,
    schema=features_df.schema,
    description="wine features"
)
```

Does it maybe have something to do with my cluster rights? I am very new to databricks and the team is also new. Basically nobody to consult. I couldn't find anything reported about this.

In general, can I expect to get good community support with databricks feature store?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've just faced the same issue. I was getting exactly the same error. When I printed the schema of the dataframe (`df.schema`) I saw that the primary key was a 'decimal' (`StructField(<<primary_key>>, DecimalType(19,0), True)`). It seems that Databricks doesn't like that type.

The solution:

```
df = df.withColumn(<<primary_key>>, df[<<primary_key>>].cast('integer'))
```

You can also use `string` instead of `integer` and that should work as well.

Note: in case you use 'string' you need to run this `spark.sql("set spark.databricks.delta.optimize.zorder.checkStatsCollection.enabled = false")`